# iOS UITextView putting character onto next line

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

[image: cut off where it says Coordinat]

In this picture with a UITextView saying "Coordinate Geometry", the "e" gets put onto the next line. There is no line space there. I have also tried this with a UILabel (I switched to UITextView to try and fix the problem but there was no difference).

Here is my code for my subclass of UITextView
    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame text:(NSString *)text circular:(BOOL)isCircular {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

```
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];//[UIColor clearColor];
        self.alpha = 0.5;
        self.textColor = [Styles mainTextColour];
        [self setFont:[Styles heading2Font]];
        [self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        self.text = text;
        self.editable = NO;

        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8, 0, -8, 0);
        [self resizeFontToFix];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Don't use BubbleText -initWithFrame:, use -initWithFrame: andText: instead");
    return nil;
}

- (void)resizeFontToFix {
    //Resize to fix
    CGFloat fontSize = self.font.pointSize;
    CGFloat minSize = 6.0 * [Styles sizeModifier];
    while (fontSize > minSize &&  [self sizeThatFits:(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX))].height >= self.frame.size.height) {
        fontSize -= 1.0;
        self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
    }

//this below resizes to fit and centres the resulting view
//    [self resizeFrameAndCentre];
}

- (void)resizeFrameAndCentre {
    CGRect originalFrame = self.frame;
    [self sizeToFit];

    CGPoint centre = self.center;
    centre.x = originalFrame.origin.x + (originalFrame.size.width / 2);
    centre.y = originalFrame.origin.y + (originalFrame.size.height / 2);
    self.center = centre;
}
```

Comment: The problem is simply that the word is too big to fit in the defined with with the given font. Use a smaller font.

Comment: I have a resize to fit method so why doesn't that resize it properly? UILabel's adjustsfontsizetofitwidth did the same thing

Comment: No, your code picks a font so the whole wrapped string fits in the allowed space but you don't check to see if individual words will fit with the selected font.

Comment: The text will depend on what the user entered as the name. Using a smaller font will only make it happen with only larger words. Is there a way to make it hyphenate?

Comment: Hyphenation isn't built into the word wrapping of `UILabel` or `UITextView`. You'll have to write your own code to insert a hyphen if any word is too big to fit.

Comment: Is there a way to detect that this is happening? I can tell the user to shorten/abbreviate the word.

Comment: As I said, you will need to check the width of individual words to see if they fit.

Comment: Should I use a character limit for the length of the words, or is that not foolproof due to characters being different widths. I want to be able to detect it without having the user see it first so I can tell them to shorten it

Comment: Also if I knew it was cut off, then i could reduce the font size.